# Sass file from npm package not found when importing in Vue-Application

Tags: webpack, sass, vue.js

When I try to import `material-components-web/material-components-web`, which I npm-installed, via SASS I get an error, telling me that the file is not found or unreadable.

I did the import inside the main `App.vue` file:

```
<style lang="sass">
    @import "material-components-web/material-components-web"
</style>
```

and the directory looks as follows:

```
node_modules/
  (lots of packages)
  @material/
    (lots of material components)
  material-components-web/
    material-components-web.scss
src/
  App.vue
  main.js
index.html
package.json
webpack.config.js
```

**My first Try fixing this:**

Obviously I thought first, the path is incorrect and tried to import `../node_modules/material-components-web/material-components` instead, which kind of worked. However `material-components-web` was importing stuff too (each individual material-component from `@material`). So even though `material-components-web` was loaded, it'd break after all.

I also saw in the source code of the vue-example of `material-components-web` that they were only importing `material-components-web/material-components` and not `../node_modules/material-components-web/material-components`, so the problem has to be somewhere else anyways.

---

So then I stumbled acroos some people who had similar issues. All of them have been told to implement something like this in their webpack config:

```
{
    loader: 'sass-loader',
    options: {
      sourceMap: true,
      includePaths: glob.sync('packages/*/node_modules').map((d) => path.join(__dirname, d)),
    },
}
```

I tried that too. Didn't work.
I cloned the [vue-example](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/c4411578d775da17c2c97d416863e5825cceb34d/framework-examples/vue) of material-components-web which shockingly didn't work either. (Though it should work right? I mean it's the official example)

So my question is: Is this a bug? And if not what am I doing wrong?

---

**Here is some more code to get an overview:**

**Full Error**

```
    ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-0219ec88","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?indentedSyntax!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0&bustCache!./src/App.vue
Module build failed: 
undefined
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: material-components-web/material-components-web.
Parent style sheet: stdin
      in somedirectory\src\App.vue (line 30, column 1)
 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-0219ec88","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?indentedSyntax!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0&bustCache!./src/App.vue 4:14-342 13:3-17:5 14:22-350
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

**Relevant parts of webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
            // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
            // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
            'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
            'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <!-- Html Stuff -->
    </div>
</template>

<style lang="sass">
    @import "material-components-web/material-components-web"
</style>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, my solution was realizing that I had imported a portion of my configuration from a sub folder and that caused @import to attempt importing the '@material/button/mdc-button' from a non-existent node_modules folder under the subfolder that contained my configuration. In the webpack build error, take a look at what paths it is trying to import from.  Your scss loader will print them out when it vomits.

Comment: Amending the path to be a relative, e.g. `@import "../../node_modules/@material/button/mdc-button";` doesn't appear to fix the issue. Then the imports called from that import fail. Now I get `File to import not found or unreadable: @material/ripple/common`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. From the error, it became clear that Webpack was trying to import the files from the same directory as the .vue file. I solution was to alter the webpack config, to include the node_modules folder. However, how to do that is no immediately clear.

With Vue CLI, you do this from the vue.config.js file to be something like the following:

```
module.exports = {
  // ... other settings ...
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                includePaths: ['node_modules']
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```